# Null Pointer Exception in Parallelstram.filter.collect

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, java-stream

I am getting NPE from the below code snippets. Not sure which object is null.

```
List<ProvisioningBrokerRequest> filteredPbRequests = allPbRequests.parallelStream().filter(
pbRequest -> pbRequest.getProvisioningRequest().getConfig().stream().anyMatch(
                config -> StringUtils.equals(uid, config.getUid()) && config.getTemplate() != null && !config
                    .getTemplate().isEmpty())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.provisioningbroker.impl.ProvisioningRequestServiceImpl.lambda$handleDeleteConnectorConfigCtlrEvent$1(ProvisioningRequestServiceImpl.java:336)[388:com..provisioning-broker-impl:18.1.1.417]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)[:1.8.0_151]
       at com.provisioningbroker.impl.ProvisioningRequestServiceImpl.handleDeleteConnectorConfigCtlrEvent(ProvisioningRequestServiceImpl.java:338)[388:com.provisioning-broker-impl:18.1.1.417]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the code into multiple lines, and it will be easier to debug. Currently, there are way too many concatenated function calls, and NPE can be thrown if any of the functions return null (e.g if allPbRequests.parallelStream() returns null, NPE will be thrown).

Comment: According to stacktrace its pointing to         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)[:1.8.0_151] , so Inside collect method has caused NPE. If am not wrong collect method has called on output of filter() so filter is not returning null then ?

Comment: @Karthik you should look at the *first* line of the stack trace, which is the actual method where the exception arose. It clearly is one of your lambda expressions. The stack trace even provides you with the line number, but since you have four method invocations in that line, there are four possibilities of what your be `null`. That’s why this answer suggests to insert line breaks.